# Remove data from an entity framework query based on something

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

My application has some privileged information, costs that certain users aren't allowed to see. The app uses WebAPI OData to pull data down into an AngularJS single page application which then hides or shows the data.

Obviously this isn't ideal, any technically savvy users can just inspect the network traffic and then view the costs.

Is there a way to remove this data from the entity framework query at the source before it's even entered my BL/Service layers?

I thought projection might help but it will break the .Include functionality and that will break my OData $extend functionality. I'm not using code first at the moment but would be willing to switch if it will help.

I fear my best option would be to ditch OData and remove the data myself at the BL or web service boundary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try with ODataConventionModelBuilder.Ignore. 
In your database context, you can do something like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Ignore(e => e.Address);
}
```

In this way, the Property Address will not show in metadata and will not show when you query .../Customers

A related post on Stackoverflow [How to prevent ODataConventionModelBuilder to automatically expose all derived types' metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257993/how-to-prevent-odataconventionmodelbuilder-to-automatically-expose-all-derived-t)